# How can I create Netbeans GUI Form without main method

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, netbeans

How can I create netbeans GUI form without main method? 
what I'm gonna do is build gui form in Netbeans, and then move the sources 
to Eclipse. beacuse netbeans is so complex and diffuclt for me, but reason to main methods of gui, I can't handle my program in eclipse. there is 2 main method in my program so I delete main method in gui form, but the program doesn't work at all. so how to create gui form without main method? is there way I can do ?

**Summary** : How Can I Create GUI Form in Netbeans without main method.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete `JForm`s `main` method by hand and move `JForm`s creation code to your `main` method? It is not that difficult...

Comment: Some error drives me crazy. But now I solved this problem. I fixed the code in my style. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by :`The program doesn't work at all?`

On Netbeans you can remove main method of  the Form and will be still able to use it.